# Regular expression pattern - floating point numbers

Tags: javascript

Can anyone give a regex pattern for the below floating point 
26.2%. It should remove '%' and give 26.2.

Comment: Have you tried yourself?

Comment: Why does it need to be a regex pattern? This should be similarly easy with standard string manipulation functions.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html (but remember, StackOverflow is not a search engine)

Comment: What regex pattern did you try? What was the result?

Comment: I tried this ([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)

Answer (score -1):

easy just use `parseFloat` there is also `parseInt` which is just casting but you need to know which to use, your example looks like it should be `parseFloat`

```
var k = "26.2%";
k = parseFloat(k);
console.log(isNaN(k)); // == FALSE because it is a number now.
```

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted you ignorant fools. It works perfectly try it dur! It's the easiest and fastest method! http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-parse wow so quick to downvote the correct method and instead quick to jump on some regex hack.